# Choose the right dimension for neural network

Tags: python, neural-network

I'm currently works with deep neural forest networks, but i have a problem to reshape the data.

Most of those algorithms works with images, but i'm working with data shape (n,m) (n rows, m columns). I'm lost with that kind of shapping

Can some help me to shape correctly the data to make predictions using those neural networks architecture please ?

Kind Regards,

Comment: This is too broad a question and depends on the type of network itself. An MLP doesn't have dimensions, just a bunch of input nodes that feed *all* intermediate nodes. You could use M*N input nodes, post each pixel value to a different node and it would work the same. Just because one node is `i` and another is `i+1` doesn't affect their weights or connections to hidden layers. Other networks, built specific for image recognition, can take location into account.

Answer (score 0):

If , You want to convert your data to 1d array then you can Flatten it.
If , you want to continue with 2d array ( or even 3d array ) , you can use Convolutional neural networks for this.